# Power BI Report Builder/SSRS Action - Go to URL link works in Report Builder but not working in PBI Service

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, action, reportbuilder

I have built a paginated report in PBI Report Builder. I have set a Text Box Properties Action - Go to URL which brings in data from a column which has a link an external URL (see link format in below not a Power BI Report).

**https://www.XXXXX.com/docp/theme/index.xhtml?targetUrl=%2Fdocp%2FXXXXX%2Fmain%2FinvoiceInput?documentId=XXXXXXX**

[Picture of How I am adding the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAwSx.png)

When I test in Report Builder the link takes me to the external website as intended. When I publish the Report to service and click the text box with the action it redirects to the link below:

https://paginated-reports.powerbi.com/#

What am I missing? Parameters already limit my textbox to a specific link so I don't need that to pass through. All documentation seems to focus on linking to another Power BI report which is not what I need.....
It works in the Builder but not published...

Comment: I don't use Power BI but the paginated reports are basically SSRS so... If you look at the link generated via the browser, is the link itself correct but getting redirected or does the link show as the 2nd link you showed in your question? Not sure if you can open your report directly from the report server with Power BI reports but if you can, check to see if that works (in standard SSRS that would be via `http://myserver/reports` or `http://myserver/reportserver` ). This might help narrow it down to PBI redirecting rather than a problem with the report itself.

Comment: When running in Builder it directs to the first link which is external  but when published it tries going to the second link. Which I think is trying force looking at the service. But I think you are on to something as I too believe it is PBI Service redirecting and not the report...